# Powershell Sum time values

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to Sum time with powershell?
I have some values and i need to get total time.

00:02:09.686 + 00:02:37.526 + 00:05:41.419 + 00:11:19.000 + 00:03:24.000 + 00:03:37.000 + = .....?

Example:
That represents Hour:00 Minutes:02 Seconds:09 Milliseconds:686

My code is something like this:

```
$timespan = [TimeSpan]::Parse($DurationColl)
$totalTime = $timespan .TotalHours
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Parse() static method isn't going to accept a collection.

You can add TimeSpan objects together to sum them.  I just did this off the top of my head but seems to work:

```
$TimeSpans =
@(
    '00:02:09.686'
    '00:02:37.526'
    '00:05:41.419'
    '00:11:19.000'
    '00:03:24.000'
    '00:03:37.000'
)

$Output = [System.TimeSpan]::new( 0 )

$TimeSpans | ForEach-Object{ $Output += $_ }

$Output.TotalHours
```

When I started this I thought I was going to have to convert each time string to a `[System.TimeSpan]` object using casting or something like `[System.TimeSpan]::Parse()`, However I think PowerShell's Type conversion system works for us here.

This code using the `.Add()` method also works, see below:

```
$Output = [System.TimeSpan]::new( 0 )
$TimeSpans | ForEach-Object{ $Output = $Output.Add( $_ ) }
```

> Note: If you feel like you have to verify the string first you may
>   want to look at the `.Parse()` and/or `.TryParse()` static methods.

Here's another approach; cast the whole array of timespan strings to a TimeSpan collection then use Measure-Object to sum the sub-property you're after:

```
[TimeSpan[]]$TimeSpans =
@(
    '00:02:09.686'
    '00:02:37.526'
    '00:05:41.419'
    '00:11:19.000'
    '00:03:24.000'
    '00:03:37.000'
)
($TimeSpans | Measure-Object -Property TotalHours -Sum).Sum
```

Also if you want the output format same as the input you can use a format specifiers from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings)

So:

`$Output -f "c"` would return: 00:28:48.6310000

I didn't play around with stripping the zeros or anything, but you should get the idea.

Sorry if this seems like options overload.  Let me know if it helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Steven thanks a lot for your help. It looks like you code is almost there. The $Output returns the Time-Span Objects. When i put $Output.TotalHours, returns 0.

Comment: Sorry I think I had a typo, can you retry?

Comment: Sure!  This line is adding the objects and the values.$TimeSpans | ForEach-Object{ $Output.Add( $_ ) }but at the end, the $Output, remain only with the Time-Span object, without any value.

Comment: Try "`foreach`ing" the array with the same command. `foreach($i in $TimeSpans){$total += $i| Measure-Object -Property TotalHours}`

Comment: That's it! Your second approach is working perfectly.

Comment: Sorry I fixed the .Add() approach, I wasn't reassigning the variable. All 3 techniques should work now.

Comment: @NekoMusume you must type cast somewhere to make that work, either the collection or $i, There are a couple of ways I supposed, but something like like: `ForEach( $i in $TimeSpans){ $Total += [timeSpan]$i }`  In my latest example I just did it on the collection and piped directly to `Measure-Object`